# How to publish an article that is only one page long?

Tags: chemistry

I am interested in publishing a journal article that is only 1 page long. Most journals want more lengthy articles. The area of focus is Chemistry. How to sort through all the requirements without reading each journal individually? I think maybe a consultant knowledgeable in this area would be ideal.

Comment: Are you sure you should not add more introduction, discussion of related research, cite more references, ...?

Comment: @J.FabianMeier  It is possible to do so but some clarity gets lost.

Comment: Yes, but depending on the field, you might be rejected just because you did not make your contribution clear enough.

Comment: For fun, "The Ratio of Proton and Electron masses", Friedrich Lenz, Phys. Rev. 82(4) 554-554 (1951), is two sentences, three lines long (four counting the one reference cited, or 8 total including title and author affiliation). Further note that it was in the "Letters to the Editor" section that became Physical Review Letters. Older Nature and other journals also often had fairly short contributions. If it is clear and concise and makes a contribution, there must be some letters journal that would take it.

Comment: Have you considered publish it as a letter in the relevant journals? 1-2 pages long letters are common in Chemistry

Answer (score 3):

Basically you’re asking to write a short letter, comment, or communication. Some, but not all, journals allow for such submissions, although usually they are in response to an existing article in the journal.

Comment: I'd walk back that "usually" to "sometimes" - my field has a large number of very short but unlinked to another article publications.

Comment: There are "letters" journals that specifically deal with short publications. But I don't see a lot of standalone "one-pagers." (I believe we are in similar areas, researchwise.)

Comment: For example, the January issue of *Infection Control and Hospital Epidemiology* has five one-page stand-alone "Letters".